# JavaScript in Google Chrome V8: hidden classes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

I study about Google Chrome V8, and I have a question about hidden classes.
V8 creates Hidden Classes for optimization, and as far as I know, child(?) objects inherit it. But, JavaScript creates 2 object, one is Object itself, another is prototype-object. My Questions are the following:

1. Is child inherit hidden-class and at the same time, share parent prototype-object?
2. In JIT Compile in V8, Chrome create machine-code instead of IR. If that, is machine-code means assembly-code dependent on user-architecture?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "*child(?)*".

Comment: "*Does machine-code mean assembly-code dependent on architecture?*" - Yes.

Answer (score 3):

V8 generates bytecode first, then architecture dependent machine code.

Hidden classes of objects are different as soon as a single property or order of property is different. Child and prototype do not have the same hidden class.